# LiveSDK + iOS login: not redirecting back to the app after allowing permissions

Tags: ios, live-sdk

I have imported liveSDK with pods, my app is set.

This is how I login in swift (I've implemented LiveAuthDelegate too):

```
var live = LiveConnectClient(clientId: ClientID, delegate: self)
live.login(self, scopes: Scopes, delegate: self)
```

1. I get the login and password screen, I sign in with my credentials.
2. I get the permissions view where I can say yes or no to the asked permissions
3. I click yes
4. I get blank page... instead of being redirected back to my app

Any ideas ?
please help

EDIT:  i think i am redirected to some page like https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf?error=server_error&lc=1033 this site and its blank? what could be the reason ?
I tried logging the url in the LiveSDK, but its crashing the app on NSLog

```
#pragma mark UIWebViewDelegate methods

(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:    (NSURLRequest *)request 
navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
NSURL *url = [request URL];

NSLog([url absoluteString]);

if ([[url absoluteString] hasPrefix: _endUrl]) 
{
[_delegate authDialogCompletedWithResponse:url];
}

// Always return YES to work around an issue on iOS 6 that returning NO may cause
// next Login request on UIWebView to hang.
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i happened to add a retaint:

```
_liveConnectClientCore = [[[LiveConnectClientCore alloc] initWithClientId:clientId
                                                               scopes:[LiveAuthHelper normalizeScoers:scopes]
                                                            delegate:delegate
                                                           userState:userState] retain];
```